# How do I search within a website using the 'requests' module?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I want to search for different company names on the website. Website link: https://www.firmenwissen.de/index.html

On this website, I want to use the search engine and search companies. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
import re

companylist = ['ABEX Dachdecker Handwerks-GmbH']

url = 'https://www.firmenwissen.de/index.html'

payloads = {
        'searchform': 'UFT-8',
        'phrase':'ABEX Dachdecker Handwerks-GmbH',
        "mainSearchField__button":'submit'
        }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

html = requests.post(url, data=payloads, headers=headers)
soup = BS(html.content, 'html.parser')
link_list= []

links = soup.findAll('a')

for li in links:
    link_list.append(li.get('href'))
print(link_list)
```

This code should bring me the next page with company information. But unfortunately, it returns only the home page. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code returns all the links in the page, what do you mean by **home page**??

Comment: Yes you are right. But code return link from home page. I want to use home page search engine to find a particular company's information. which unfortunately i am unable. This should take me to the next page where a search result will show.

Comment: The page uses javascript, which `requests` module doesn't support. Try using something like selenium instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your initial url you are doing search for. Grab the appropriate `href`s only and add to a set to ensure no duplicates (or alter selector to return only one match if possible); add those items to a final set for looping to ensure only looping required number of links. I have used `Session` on assumption you will repeat for many companies.

Iterate over the set using selenium to navigate to each company url and extract whatever info you need.

This is an outline.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
companyList = ['ABEX Dachdecker Handwerks-GmbH','SUCHMEISTEREI GmbH']

url = 'https://www.firmenwissen.de/ergebnis.html'
baseUrl = 'https://www.firmenwissen.de'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

finalLinks = set()

## searches section; gather into set

with requests.Session() as s:
    for company in companyList:
        payloads = {
        'searchform': 'UFT-8',
        'phrase':company,
        "mainSearchField__button":'submit'
        }

        html = s.post(url, data=payloads, headers=headers)
        soup = BS(html.content, 'lxml')

        companyLinks = {baseUrl + item['href'] for item in soup.select("[href*='firmeneintrag/']")}
        # print(soup.select_one('.fp-result').text)
        finalLinks = finalLinks.union(companyLinks)

for item in finalLinks:
    d.get(item)
    info  = d.find_element_by_css_selector('.yp_abstract_narrow')
    address =  d.find_element_by_css_selector('.yp_address')
    print(info.text, address.text)

d.quit()
```

---

Just the first links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
companyList = ['ABEX Dachdecker Handwerks-GmbH','SUCHMEISTEREI GmbH', 'aktive Stuttgarter']

url = 'https://www.firmenwissen.de/ergebnis.html'
baseUrl = 'https://www.firmenwissen.de'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

finalLinks = []

## searches section; add to list

with requests.Session() as s:
    for company in companyList:
        payloads = {
        'searchform': 'UFT-8',
        'phrase':company,
        "mainSearchField__button":'submit'
        }

        html = s.post(url, data=payloads, headers=headers)
        soup = BS(html.content, 'lxml')

        companyLink = baseUrl + soup.select_one("[href*='firmeneintrag/']")['href']
        finalLinks.append(companyLink)

for item in set(finalLinks):
    d.get(item)
    info  = d.find_element_by_css_selector('.yp_abstract_narrow')
    address =  d.find_element_by_css_selector('.yp_address')
    print(info.text, address.text)
d.quit()
```

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you meant?

Comment: thank you very very much. Your code is perfectly working as I am looking for. But I want to grab address:                                                                             abex Dachdecker Handwerks GmbH
Weingartener Str. 31
76229 Karlsruhe, Deutschland

Comment: Yea I did thank you. But there is a problem. If I use this company name 'aktive Stuttgarter'. Code run all the link. I just want to go first link which is the right company information. how can i select first link.

Comment: Yes that fine too. Thank you.

Comment: got this error ''TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing''

Comment: it show some error: **WebDriverException: unknown error**

Comment: what is this? is it related to my problem?

Comment: it is the solution. I have also edited the same thing into the answer at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you thousands time. One last question, if it not too much for you. if you use **aktive Stuttgarter** you go to next page and you see address. If you click **E-Mail-Adresse hinzufügen** you can see email address. It's actually a link which take you to may be next page. can i get this link and go next. what do you think how can i do that?

Comment: I think you should ask as a new question as I might restructure code  based on new requirements.